# Is there a way to insert <Picker.Item /> into <Picker> </Picker> with the array?

Tags: javascript, react-native

The code I wrote for Picker is as follows,but I can not overwrite and execute Picker items with the array.
How can I do this?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View,Picker} from 'react-native';

export default class TA extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1,alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Picker style={{width: 150,height: 60}} selectedValue="1">
                <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
                <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
                <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
                <Picker.Item label="4" value="4" />
                <Picker.Item label="5" value="5" />
                <Picker.Item label="6" value="6" />

                //from here onwards

                {()=>{
                   let p = [];
                   for(let i = 7 ; i < 12 ; i++){
                      p.push(<Picker.Item label={i} value={i} />)
                   }
                   return p;
                }}

                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: what the array do you want to use?

Comment: To make it easier to work with ```<Picker.Item/>```

Comment: Do you need to render this array `[7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`?

Answer (score 0):

In render method you can create a variable as below:

```
 let pickerItems =
  
  pickerArray.map((value, index) => {
    return (
      <Picker.Item
        label={value}
        value={value}
      />
    );
  });
```

and use this variable in your picker like this:

```
 <Picker>
   {pickerItems}
 </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

It one of the solution based on your code

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Picker} from 'react-native';

export default class TA extends React.Component {
    render(){
      
      const myArr = () => {
        var p = [];
        for(let i = 7 ; i < 12 ; i++){
          p.push(i)
        } return p;
      }
      var newArr = myArr() 

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1,alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Picker style={{width: 150,height: 60}} selectedValue="1">
                <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
                <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
                <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
                <Picker.Item label="4" value="4" />
                <Picker.Item label="5" value="5" />
                <Picker.Item label="6" value="6" />

                {newArr.map((item, index) => {
                   return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={index}/>) 
                })}
  
                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-vaughan-dt742?file=/src/Select.js:0-908

Comment: completed source is in [CodeSandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-burnell-yh5s4)